# Magento2 Mobile SSO - OAuth-based authentication

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I have been asked by a mobile dev to provide Magento 2 API to create a single sign-on application for my store.  I have provided this info:

```
•   curl -X POST "https://example.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token" -H "Content-Type: application/JSON" -d '{"username":"user@email.com","password": "password"}'

token for above user : "ypilvsgqpfye3wkary6kkqkjpmsscfzxc" 
•   curl -X GET "https://example.com/rest/V1/customers/me" -H "Authorization: Bearer ypilvsgqpfye3wkary6kkqkjpmsscfzxc"

customer information.
•   $ curl -X GET "https://example.com/rest/V1/customers/me" -H "Authorization: Bearer ypilvsgqpfye3wkary6kkqkjpmsscfzxc"
```

is this enough for them to get the information to build the app and get users to log in? OR is there something that I am missing to provide? Any advice is appreciated.